# How to create a JSON column by grouping a different column without STRING_AGG (SQL Server)

Tags: json, sql-server, group-by, sql-server-2016

I have a table like this:

```
ID  Number
A    10
A    11
B    10
C     9
C    10
...  ...
```

I want to create a view in SQL Server as the following:

```
id   number
A    [10,11]
B    [10]
C    [9,10]
...
```

I created in PostgreSQL The following:

```
CREATE VIEW "EXAMPLE" AS
SELECT 
ID as "id",
json_agg (Number Order By Number DESC) AS "number"
FROM "exampleX"
GROUP BY ID
```

How I can do it in sql server without using STRING_AGG.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: If you have access to `STRING_AGG` you have access to `FOR JSON` too.

Comment: SQL SERVER 2016

Comment: Oh, so you don't have `STRING_AGG`; so when you say without `STRING_AGG` you mean that you can't use it due to the version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old method of aggregating strings, prior to `STRING_AGG` (which was added in SQL Server 2017), is using `FOR XML PATH` and a subquery:

```
WITH YourTable AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
    ('A',10),
    ('A',11),
    ('B',10),
    ('C', 9),
    ('C',10))V(ID,Number))
SELECT YT.ID,
       STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(',',sq.Number)
              FROM YourTable sq
              WHERE sq.ID = YT.ID
              FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','varchar(MAX)'),1,1,'') AS Numbers
FROM YourTable YT
GROUP BY YT.ID;
```

Comment: Thank you, This solution solved my problem. But how can I do the "order by Number DESC" in this solution?

Comment: Just add the `ORDER BY` to the subquery, @zero .